# Regex: retrieve from URL everything between www. and .com

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use PHP's `preg_match()` to retrieve everything between the `www.` and `.com` of a URL.

e.g.:

`www.example.com` will return `example`

`www.example-website.com` will return `example-website`

I'm lucky in that the URLs I'm working with ***always*** start `www.` and always end `.com`, so it doesn't need to be particularly complex, accounting for many use cases.

However, my Regex knowledge is minimal to none.

My try:

```
preg_match("/.([^.]*)./", $string, $matches);
```

As according to [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) the second match (`$matches[1]`?) should contain what I need, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks.

Comment: The answers here are good for your case where the URLs always start with `www` and end with `com`, but a more generic regular expression would be `\w+\.(.+?)\.\w+`. That will match URLs with subdomains and other TLDs such as `subdomain.example.net`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the dots in the regex.

```
preg_match("/www\.([^.]*)\.com/", $string, $matches);
```

`.` in a regex can match (nearly) any character,

where as

`\.` matches only the literal `.` dot within the url.

`www` and `com` can be used for delimiting the string in the url which gives extra safety.

Example : http://regex101.com/r/aA5eC5/2

The first capture group (`\1`) will contain

```
example
example-website
```

**EDIT**

If the regex is to match strings with other `.` in it, something like `www.example.somesite.com`, then the regex can be modified as

```
preg_match("/www\.(.+)\.com/", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Won't match URLs with several subdomains as `www.example.somesite.com`

Comment: @Mateon1 it wont because OP wants something very minimal as in example provided

Comment: Also, shouldn't the backslashes in the first example be doubled? I don't know PHP very well since I haven't touched it in years, but this is still a string and literal `\ ` should be escaped with another one (`\\ `)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=www\.)(.+?)(?=\.com)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iZ9sO5/10

Comment: This matches `www..com`, try `(.+?)`

Comment: @Flosculus: validating the url format is not the goal here.